# Links no javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor

Bom dia pessoal, estou com um problema ao chamar um link no javascript, no php tenho uma regra onde todas vez que colocar #URL#link.... ela substitui pelo endereço do servidor. Exemplo #URL#public ele substitui para http://localhost/public, no javascript não consegui fazer funcionar. Se alguém puder me dar uma ajuda, vou colocar minha regra em php, e abaixo o javascript onde preciso ajustar.

php.config

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',true);
define('URL','http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/sistema/');
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('PATH', getcwd().DS );
define('TEMPLATE', PATH.'view'.DS.'template.html');
```

Javascript que precisa ser ajustado

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '#URL#sistema/public/plugin/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php';
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '#URL#sistema/public/plugin/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?type=images';
    config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '#URL#sistema/public/plugin/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?type=flash';
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '#URL#sistema/public/plugin/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?type=files';
    config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '#URL#sistema/public/plugin/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?type=images';
    config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '#URL#sistema/public/plugin/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?type=flash';
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver dessa maneira.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
        config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = url+'public/plugin/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php';
        config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = url+'public/plugin/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?type=images';
        config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = url+'public/plugin/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?type=flash';
        config.filebrowserUploadUrl = url+'public/plugin/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?type=files';
        config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = url+'public/plugin/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?type=images';
        config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = url+'public/plugin/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?type=flash';
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Na página onde carrega o script do CKEditor, coloque isso

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ckeditor_global_url = <?php echo URL;?>;
</script>
```

Algum outro script que utilize uma variável de nome igual poderá conflitar. Então, por isso nesse exemplo usamos um nome que dificilmente colidiria com outro em uso.

Algo mais elegante e "seguro" seria aplica namespace, mas o exemplo tornaria-se mais complicado. Caso tenha interesse em aprimorar os seus scripts, procure por javascript orientado a objeto.

Continuando, no script do CKEditor, trocaria para isso:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
    config.baseHref = ckeditor_global_url;
    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = 'public/plugin/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php';
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = 'public/plugin/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?type=images';
    config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = 'public/plugin/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?type=flash';
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = 'public/plugin/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?type=files';
    config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = 'public/plugin/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?type=images';
    config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = 'public/plugin/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?type=flash';
};
```

Aqui apenas definimos um valor para a propriedade [config.baseHref](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.baseHref).

Por fim, há formas diferentes para resolver. Como não deu muitos detalhes de como estão as suas páginas, quais as circunstâncias, etc, é inviável palpitar qual o melhor modo ou ao menos qual o modo mais apropriado para o seu caso.

Comment: Esse método não consegui adaptar. Daí fui tentando e consegui arrumar. Obrigado.